# How can I control the distribution of instances in geometric nodes with lights?

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes

Such as distributing seedlings on objects illuminated by light.[image]

Comment: What kind of "control" do you want?

Comment: For example, the weight of the vertex group is higher where the light is irradiated, and the weight of the vertex group is biased to zero if it is not irradiated by the light, so as to control the distribution of examples on the model surface.